# How do I create a JWK from PFX certificate?

Tags: .net-core-3.1

Background: I'm trying to create a JWK from a PFX file so that I'm able to use the [Okta SDK](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet).

The OktaClient expects the private key in the form of a JWK. An example I stole from their unit tests looks like.

```json
{
    "p": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "q": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "d": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "kid": "3d3062f5-16a4-42b5-837b-19b6ef1a0edc",
    "qi": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "dp": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "dq": "{{lots_of_characters}}",
    "n": "{{lots_of_characters}}"
}
```

Everything I've tried results in the exception "Something went wrong when creating the signed JWT. Verify your private key." I believe this is because I'm losing the private key part of the cert when I use the IdentityModel convert method (noted below).

```cs
var signingCert = new X509Certificate2("{{my_cert}}.pfx", "{{my_passphrase}}");
var privateKey = signingCert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(privateKey);

// The "HasPrivateKey" flag is suddenly false on the resulting object from this method
var rsaJwk = JsonWebKeyConvert.ConvertFromRSASecurityKey(rsaSecurityKey);

var rsaJwkSerialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rsaJwk);

var oktaClientConfig = new OktaClientConfiguration
{
    OktaDomain = "{{my_okta_domain}}",
    ClientId = {{my_client_id}},
    AuthorizationMode = AuthorizationMode.PrivateKey,
    PrivateKey = new JsonWebKeyConfiguration(rsaJwkSerialized);,
    Scopes = new List<string> {"okta.users.manage"}
};

var oktaClient = new OktaClient(oktaClientConfig);

// This throws when trying to self-sign the JWT using my private key
var oktaUsers = await oktaClient.Users.ListUsers().ToArrayAsync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after days of trying to figure this out, found it mere hours after finally posting on SO.

It turns out there are flags you set when you create the X509Certificate2 that can tell the cert that it is exportable and this is required for the JsonWebKeyConverter to properly create the JWK.

```cs
var signingCert = new X509Certificate2("{{my_cert}}.pfx", "{{my_passphrase}}", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create **string extension** to generate SHA-512 of a string

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
namespace MyNamespace;

public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get sha-512
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Sha512(this string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return null;
        }

        using var sha = SHA512.Create();
        var textData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var hash = sha.ComputeHash(textData);
        return string.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
    }
}
```

2- Create an X509Certificate extension to export the JWK (private or public)

**Note:** The extension require [identity model](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) to be installed from nuget.

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using JsonWebAlgorithmsKeyTypes = IdentityModel.Jwk.JsonWebAlgorithmsKeyTypes;
using JsonWebKey = IdentityModel.Jwk.JsonWebKey;

namespace MyNamespace;

public static class X509CertificateExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get RSA public json web key from certificate
    /// JWK: <see href="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificate"><see cref="X509Certificate2"/></param>
    /// <param name="use">Key usage</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JsonWebKey GetRsaPublicJwk(this X509Certificate2 certificate,
        string use = default)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var key = new JsonWebKey
        {
            X5c = {Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.RawData)},
            Kty = JsonWebAlgorithmsKeyTypes.RSA,
            X5t = certificate.Thumbprint
        };

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(certificate.PublicKey.GetRSAPublicKey()?.ToXmlString(false) ?? string.Empty);
        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/Modulus") is { } modulus &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(modulus.InnerText))
        {
            key.N = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(modulus.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/Exponent") is { } exponent &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exponent.InnerText))
        {
            key.E = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(exponent.InnerText));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key.E) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key.N))
        {
            key.Kid = $"{key.N}{key.E}".Sha512();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(use))
        {
            key.Use = use;
        }

        return key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get RSA private json web key from certificate
    /// JWK: <see href="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificate"><see cref="X509Certificate2"/></param>
    /// <param name="use">Key usage</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static JsonWebKey GetRsaPrivateJwk(this X509Certificate2 certificate,
        string use = default)
    {
        if (certificate is not {HasPrivateKey: true})
        {
            return null;
        }

        var key = new JsonWebKey
        {
            X5c = {Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.RawData)},
            Kty = JsonWebAlgorithmsKeyTypes.RSA,
            X5t = certificate.Thumbprint
        };

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()?.ToXmlString(true) ?? string.Empty);

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/P") is { } p &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.InnerText))
        {
            key.P = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(p.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/Q") is { } q &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.InnerText))
        {
            key.Q = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(q.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/D") is { } d &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.InnerText))
        {
            key.D = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(d.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/Exponent") is { } exponent &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exponent.InnerText))
        {
            key.E = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(exponent.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/InverseQ") is { } inverseQ &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inverseQ.InnerText))
        {
            key.QI = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(inverseQ.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/DQ") is { } dq &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dq.InnerText))
        {
            key.DQ = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(dq.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/DP") is { } dp &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dp.InnerText))
        {
            key.DP = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(dp.InnerText));
        }

        if (document.SelectSingleNode("/RSAKeyValue/Modulus") is { } modulus &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(modulus.InnerText))
        {
            key.N = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Convert.FromBase64String(modulus.InnerText));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key.E) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key.N))
        {
            key.Kid = $"{key.N}{key.E}".Sha512();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(use))
        {
            key.Use = use;
        }

        return key;
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)